# Gazebo crashes using skid_steer, but works fine with diff_drive

Tags: ros, gazebo, diff-drive-controller, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a skid steer robot which I'm trying to simulate in Gazebo. In my wheel macro, I have:

```
    <transmission name="${wheel_prefix}_transmission">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="${wheel_prefix}_wheel_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="${wheel_prefix}_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
```

and in my main `urdf` I have:

```
<plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
  <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
  <leftFrontJoint>front_left_wheel_joint</leftFrontJoint>
  <rightFrontJoint>front_right_wheel_joint</rightFrontJoint>
  <leftRearJoint>back_left_wheel_joint</leftRearJoint>
  <rightRearJoint>back_right_wheel_joint</rightRearJoint>
  <wheelSeparation>${wheelbase}</wheelSeparation>
  <wheelDiameter>${2*wheel_radius}</wheelDiameter>
  <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
  <torque>20</torque>
  <commandName>cmd_vel</topicName>
  <broadcastTF>false</broadcastTF>
</plugin>
```

If I use a diff drive controller, like this:

```
<plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>20</updateRate>
  <leftJoint>front_left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
  <rightJoint>front_right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
  <wheelSeparation>${wheelbase}</wheelSeparation>
  <wheelDiameter>${2*wheel_radius}</wheelDiameter>
  <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
  <torque>20</torque>
  <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
  <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
  <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
</plugin>
```

Then things work and I can at least use teleop to move the robot backwards and forwards in Gazebo. Any attempt to use the skid steer plugin and Gazebo crashes immediately. It doesn't ever produce a log file, which is unhelpful, so I have no idea what's causing it to break. If I comment out the transmission elements in my xacro file, then Gazebo loads, but obviously I don't get a `cmd_vel` topic etc. So I guess it's something in the transmission blocks that needs twiddling.

Is there a way to enable verbose output from Gazebo via the launch file?

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch" />
```

It doesn't help that the main documentation is out of date, e.g. it suggets `<topicName>` which is a deprecated tag, so I don't know if I'm setting up correctly.

Here's the stdout:

```
started roslaunch server http://control:33695/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.12
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4819]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2ed86bbe-18a4-11e8-99e9-78d00420dd75
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4832]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [4842]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [4858]
process[spawn_urdf-4]: started with pid [4866]
[ INFO] [1519395408.516996288]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1519395408.518270471]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1519395408.906177783, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1519395408.941460375, 0.056000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ WARN] [1519395409.123089568, 0.149000000]: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) missing <commandTopic>, defaults to "cmd_vel"
[ WARN] [1519395409.123128894, 0.149000000]: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) missing <odometryTopic>, defaults to "odom"
[ WARN] [1519395409.123145859, 0.149000000]: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) missing <odometryFrame>, defaults to "odom"
[ WARN] [1519395409.123172229, 0.149000000]: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) missing <covariance_x>, defaults to 0.000100
[ WARN] [1519395409.123191756, 0.149000000]: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) missing <covariance_y>, defaults to 0.000100
[ WARN] [1519395409.123209074, 0.149000000]: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) missing <covariance_yaw>, defaults to 0.010000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 4842, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/control/.ros/log/2ed86bbe-18a4-11e8-99e9-78d00420dd75/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/control/.ros/log/2ed86bbe-18a4-11e8-99e9-78d00420dd75/gazebo-2*.log
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/control/.ros/log/2ed86bbe-18a4-11e8-99e9-78d00420dd75/spawn_urdf-4*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283536/gazebo-crashes-using-skid_steer,-but-works-fine-with-diff_drive/) by [josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33840/josh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-02-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2018-02-23**:\

> So I guess it's something in the transmission blocks that needs twiddling.

Probably not. It's more likely that the plugin just doesn't reach the point where it's crashing because it aborts before when it cannot find the transmissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out to be an embarassingly simple problem with joint names, but without gazebo running in verbose mode, there's no feedback.

I changed my launch file to include:

```
 <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="verbose" value="true"/>
    <!--arg name="debug" value="true"/-->
 </include>
```

Which then gave me the more useful output:

```
[Err] [gazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.cpp:273] EXCEPTION: GazeboRosSkidSteerDrive Plugin (ns = //) couldn't get left rear hinge joint named "back_left_wheel_joint"

[Err] [Model.cc:1010] Exception occured in the Load function of plugin with name[skid_steer_drive_controller] and filename[libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so]. This plugin will not run.
```

Although I guess this is a bug in Gazebo, it should fail to load the plugin, not crash out entirely.

This error wasn't caught with the diff_drive controller because I was using the front wheels joints. My back wheels were prefixed with `rear` not `back` hence the failure.

---

Originally posted by [josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33840/josh/) with karma: 41 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Max Kiva](https://answers.ros.org/users/31584/max-kiva/) on 2018-02-27**:
Exactly the same problem ! Thanks !

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2021-10-29**:
Same here! Thanks

**Comment by [ymzkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/72276/ymzkp/) on 2022-04-19**:
Thanks! This Helped